# How to change data from row to column

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I've interactive report with data

```
Name    STATUS  CNT
----------------------------
Vinu    20Q1    595
Kuma    19Q2    31
john    19Q3    502
Stev    19Q4    458
```

but, I need this to be in format.

```
Name    20Q1 19Q3 19Q2 19Q1
-----------------------------------
Vinu    XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX
Kuma    XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX
John    XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX
Stev    XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX
```

Comment: Is the set of columns that you want in the result known at compile time?  Or only at runtime?  It looks like these are quarter numbers-- are you expecting that the number of columns will increase over time

Comment: Yes, columns will change once the quater changes, we need to consider last 4 quater. I dont know the difference between compile time and runtime, sorry, i'm new to apex

Comment: This is called a pivot query. In APEX 5.1 and later the interactive report supports pivot queries declaratively. I would try that first.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a SQL problem, using REGEXP_REPLACE
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490

```
select regexp_replace('19Q3 502','\w','x') from dual

REGEXP_R
--------
xxxx xxx
```

How this is applied really depends on your data structure, which you didn't provide.

Comment: Perhaps I've misinterpreted the scantily written question. Is this a pivot problem? If the declarative option is no good, and you have a varying number of columns, there are some dynamic pivot options http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/07/exploring-dynamic-pivot-options.html